# Выборка данных из двух таблиц

Tags: mysql

Нужно выбрать данные сразу из двух таблиц item_images и item_main, причём у item_images должен быть лимит 1. Слепливаю так, но ничего не выводит

```
//тут выборка из главной таблицы item_main, далее склейка
JOIN (SELECT id_item AS id_item2 FROM item_images ORDER BY ASC limit 1) item_images2
ON item_main.id_item = item_images2.id_item2
```

**Обновление**

```
INNER JOIN item_images 
     ON item_main.id_item = item_images.id_item
```

Это работает, но лимит впихнуть туда никак

Comment: Может нет пересечения (ведь вы берете всего одну строку из вложенного запроса)? Накидайте пример на sqlfiddle.

Comment: Обовил вопрос

Comment: так-то всё работает

    select * from generator_16 JOIN (SELECT n as n1 from generator_16 limit 1) g16_1 on generator_16.n=g16_1.n1\G
    *************************** 1. row ***************************
     n: 0
    n1: 0
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, для каждого из item-ом вам нужно вывести одно изображение. В этом случае можно воспользоваться соединением `LEFT JOIN`, которое каждой записи из `item_main` сопоставит одну или ноль записей из `item_images`

```
SELECT
  it.*,
  im.*
FROM
  item_main AS it
LEFT JOIN
  item_images AS im
ON
  it.id_item = im.id_item
```